# A name for this primitive operation?

Tags: animation, graphics, terminology

I use this function a *lot* in game/graphics programming.

```
float slide(float from, float to, float by) {
    float difference = to - from;
    if(difference > by) {
        return from + by;
    } else if(difference < -by) {
        return from - by;
    } else {
        return to;
    }
}
```

The basic idea is "move towards so-and-so by this much".

I've called it `slide` because if you call it each frame on something's position, it appears as sliding with constant speed towards a target position.

Any other suggestions for naming?

Comment: Seems to be a form of [linear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation)?

Comment: I don't know an official name.  I would probably use "advance".

Comment: It is kind of like `lerp` in a way, except that `by` is expressed as an "outside" unit rather than a factor of the difference. But it sits right next to `lerp` in my utilities library.

Comment: lerp, which stands for "linear interpolation"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think slide is OK, maybe moveTo or floatTo would be also OK.

And one more idea. when you use this function like this:

```
Slide(0, 5, 10);
```

(menaing that "by" is bigger than possible step)

and you'll call it several times, the object will oscilate around "to" position.

You should add some handling for it. Like:

```
float slide(float from, float to, float by) {
    float difference = to - from;
    if(difference > by && from + by < to) {
        return from + by;
    } else if(difference < -by && from - by > to) {
        return from - by;
    } else {
        return to;
    }
}
```

hope this will help.

Comment: Hi, thank you, but the function already handles this scenario as written :)